# Not giving access to certain method in controller when session is not set in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want user to not access certain method of controller when session is not set. For this I can check session in all method and if session is set then only go to furthur else redirect to specific page. Since I have many method that I don't want user to take access if session is not set. Its bulk to go through all method and check session. Are there any shortcut way to obtain this functionality.

I tried checking session is constructor method of controller but it works for all method. But I want only specific method to block if session is not set. How to do it.

Example:

```
class dashboard extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('dbmodel');
    $this->load->helper('url','form');


    //verified user check
    if($this->session->userdata("unverified") != FALSE) {
        redirect("verify_user");  

    }

    }
    //verified user check
}
```

Above code, redirects to verify_user controller as soon as 'unverified' session is found when user go to dashboard controller. But I want to give access to some method of dashboard controller. Not all method. Where as this code redirects whenever session is found and don't give access to any method of dashboard controller.

Comment: add some code related your Question

Comment: I have added code related to my question

Comment: Which version of CI you use???

Comment: Codeigniter version 2.2

Comment: it s good to be check the session in **constructor** but if you want to access some  sessions to another functions then you have to put conditions on every function. example
`function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function chk_login(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
echo "some action";
}else{
redirect('login');  

    }    }   `

Comment: Its a lengthy way. Short process has already mentioned with accpected answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this It might help you

```
class MY_controller extends CI_controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function _required_user($params =array()){
        $action =$this->router->fetch_method();
        if(empty($params['except']))
            $params['except'] =array();
        if(empty($params['only']))
            $params['only'] =array();
        if(count($params['except']) > 0 && in_array($action,$params['except']))
            return true;    
        if(count($params['only']) > 0 && in_array($action,$params['only']) && $this->session->userdata('is_login'))
            return true;
        if($this->session->userdata('is_login'))    
            return true;
        redirect('login');  

    }       
}

class dashboard extends MY_Controller {

  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('dbmodel');
        $this->load->helper('url','form');
        $this->_required_user(array('except'=>array('index')))      
    }
    function add(){
    /*
    Session required
    */  
    }
    function edit(){
    /*
    Session required
    */  
    }
    function index(){
    /*
    no session required
    */
    }
  }

 class content extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('dbmodel');
        $this->load->helper('url','form');
        $this->_required_user(array('only'=>array('index')))        
    }
    function add(){
    /*
    no Session required
    */  
    }
    function edit(){
    /*
    no Session required
    */  
    }
    function index(){
    /*
    session required
    */
    }
 }  
class Myaccount extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        /*
        for all functions session required
        */
        $this->_required_user()     

    }
    function edit(){
    /*
    session required
    */
    }
    function save(){
    /*
    session required
    */
    }
 }
```

1. Only param: check session is exist for only given functions/function
2. Except param: Don't check session for given functions/function
3. No Param : check session for all function in controller and redirect

You can modified _reuired_user function according to your requirement

Comment: I wrote above code. And then also I can access the method like add without session. Also after form submit new tab is opened.

Comment: I need to modify some code with my requirement and it successfully worked. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! glad to hear it worked out!  Can you share what changes you did ?

Comment: Changes for me was. I had to do nested if statement inside ` if(count($params['only']) > 0 && in_array($action,$params['only']) && $this->session->userdata('is_login'))` variable to check if `verified` session is true and set.

Answer (score 4):

you can try the following - if it helps

create in your application/core folder a class named MY_Controller
something like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function checkUserSession()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata("unverified") != FALSE) 
        {
            redirect("verify_user");
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

after that your dashboard controller should look like

```
class dashboard extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function show_dashboard()
    {
        if ($this->checkUserSession())
        {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is lengthy if I have many methods that are already made. I don't want to go through methods and check session every time. I want to check session in specific methods only.

Comment: don't understand what you mean - because my suggestion doest exactly what you want - just write in every method where you want to check the session `if ($this->checkUserSession()){....}` and thats it

Comment: I wouldnot write in every method. As mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Create a library with any name i created Users.

```
class Users 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    function _is_logged()
    {
        if(!$this->ci->session->has_userdata('unverified'))
        {
            redirect('verify_user');
        }
    }
}
```

Load the library or put it in to autoload in `application/config/autoload.php`

Then just call the function at the top of your methods which one you want to restrict.

```
function abc()
{
    $this->users->_is_logged();
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

can you check like this?

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function chk_login()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
         echo "some action";
    }
    else
    {
         redirect('login');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but suggestion based on my experience :

As a developer it is easy if it is done like the above mentioned answer by @user1048123.

But for example if you are accessing the method(ex: index) for which session is not needed but still `function _required_user()` method has to be processed before the index getting displayed where you have to passed larger array( ex:30 methods in array name) . This will slow down the loading time of methods for which session is not needed .So for better performance check the session is the method (in each method ) for which session is needed to be checked.

This idea might be older but it really matters performance when you have alrger number of methods or users are larger.

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
<?php
    class dashboard extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->model('dbmodel');
            $this->load->helper('url','form');


        }

        public function index()
        {
            $user = $this->session->userdata("unverified")//asign session value to variauble
            $result = $this->dbmodel->check_user($user);//check user validity

        if(empty($result))
        {
            //user is not verified
            $this->load->view('unverified_loging');
        }
        else
        {
            //user is verified
            $this->load->view('verified_loging');
        }

    }
```

In Model

```
    public function check_user($user)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE <argument here>");//check with database
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;

    }
```

If user is satisfied with the `validity` user then it pass the data to `$result`. Else if not satisfied with the `validity` it will return `$result` as `NULL`.

So in controller you can check whether `$result` its empty or not