# In Codeigniter 3.0, How to load my custom library for all controllers except only login controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to search on google for this question.
I really want to load my MY_Login Library to all my controllers for check session. (not one by one)
but except only login controller i don't want to load in.

**Library**

```
class MY_Login {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // call with constructor.
        $this->isLogin();
    }

    function isLogin() {
         //source code
    }  
}
```

Any comments would be appreciated :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261007/not-giving-access-to-certain-method-in-controller-when-session-is-not-set-in-cod/31316000#31316000

Comment: Thanks. It helps me alot ^^

Comment: Glade its help..you can upvote that aswer too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use core MY_Controller on controllers like dashboard etc

application > core > MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('login');
}

}
```

Controller

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

  public function index() {

  }

}
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
Library example

```
class Login {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    $this->CI->load->library('session');

    if ($this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged') == TRUE) {

    } else {

     $this->logout();

    }
  }

  public function login
      // How to use session in library example.

     $this->CI->session->set_userdata(array('is_logged'=> true)); 
  }


  public function logout() {
    $this->CI->session_unset_userdata('is_logged');
  }


 }
```

I would suggest reading more of the user guide first. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html