# Codeigniter Restrict Admin Page via URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a website wherein I have an admin and user page. I have a problem wherein I can access the admin page via URL even though I am logged in as a user. I have validation checks at the login page, however if I am already logged in as a user or as an admin, I can access all the pages. I want to restrict the pages to their roles only. Here's my code.

MY_Controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();

    $session_admin = $this->session->userdata('isAdmin');
    $method = $this->router->fetch_method();

    if(($session_admin == FALSE) && $method != 'login')
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', 'You need to login to access this location' );
      redirect('user_home');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('admin_ticketing/new_tickets');
    }
}

function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) {
        redirect('login');
        die();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_role()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('role', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
         $data = array(
            'userid' => $result->userid,
            'username' => $result->username,
            'password' => $result->password,
            'firstname' => $result->firstname,
            'lastname' => $result->lastname,
            'email' => $result->email,
            'address' => $result->address,
            'monthly_dues' => $result->monthly_dues,
            'arrears' => $result->arrears,
            'isAdmin' => true,
            'contactnum' => $result->contactnum,
            'role' => $result->role,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_user()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('role', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
         $data = array(
            'userid' => $result->userid,
            'username' => $result->username,
            'password' => $result->password,
            'firstname' => $result->firstname,
            'lastname' => $result->lastname,
            'email' => $result->email,
            'address' => $result->address,
            'monthly_dues' => $result->monthly_dues,
            'arrears' => $result->arrears,
            'isAdmin' => false,
            'contactnum' => $result->contactnum,
            'role' => $result->role,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_active()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('isActive', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function validate_login()
{
    $this->load->model('model_accounts');
    $valid = $this->model_accounts->validate();
    $isAdmin = $this->model_accounts->check_role();
    $isUser = $this->model_accounts->check_user();
    $isActive = $this->model_accounts->check_active();

    if($valid && $isAdmin && $isActive) // Active Admin
    {
        redirect('admin_ticketing/new_tickets');
    }
    else if($valid && $isActive && $isUser)  // Active User
    {
        redirect('user_home');
    }
    else if(($valid && $isAdmin) && $isActive == false)  //Deactivated Admin
    {
        redirect('login/admindeact');
    }
    else if($valid && ($isActive && $isAdmin) == false) //Deactivated User
    {
        redirect('login/userdeact');
    }
    else if($valid == false) //Invalid Account
    {
        $data['message'] = "Sorry, the username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again. ";
        $this->template->load('template', 'view_login', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261007/not-giving-access-to-certain-method-in-controller-when-session-is-not-set-in-cod/31316000#31316000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this in your controller, See this code,

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $session_admin = $this->session->userdata('admin'); //getting admin session
    $method = $this->router->fetch_method(); // get the current method

    if(empty($session_admin) && $method != 'login'){ // check for admin session and methos is login
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', 'You need to login to access this location' );
        redirect('admin/users/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to place this in MY_Controller so that I won't have to repeat this every controller?

Comment: How do I implement this? If I put this in MY_Controller, the page redirects too many times and returns an error

Comment: @coderszx you need to put this this code on every admin controllers. For the controller with login functionality you need the the method checking code. otherwise just use the admin session checking code.

Comment: won't the construct in my admin controller override the construct in MY_Controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set roles for admin and front-user simply at the time of login, set a session value 'is_admin'

Then you can check if($is_admin) like that.

Comment: So i need to check it for every controller and its functions?

Comment: just add a check in constructor of every controller.