# Codeigniter - How to avoid user entering logged page without login?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have Controller called `login.php` that will take login credentials, if true user will be directed to a method `profile()` in another controller called `page.php`.
In that `profile()` method only contain a command to load the view of user's profile.
So the route is like this: 
Home->login->profie 
But when I try to bypass the login process via url like this 
Home->profile 
The system still accept that. How can I make a rule that a user can't open profile if they're not logged in?

Here's the **Controller:**

page.php

```
class page extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE);
        $this->load->library('form_validation');    
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->status = $this->config->item('status'); 
        $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_front');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }


    function login() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_login');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }

    function register() {

       $this->load->view('page_header');
       $this->load->view('content_register');
       $this->load->view('page_footer');

   }  


    function profile(){

        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_profile');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');

    }

    function success() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_success');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }

    function logout()
    {
            //destroy session
        $data = array('login' => '', 'uname' => '', 'uid' => '');
        $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('page/index');
    }


}


?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html','security'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //get form input
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fail
            $this->load->view('content_login');
        }
        else
        {
            //check user credentials
            $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($username, $password);
            if(count($uresult)>0)
            {
                //set session
                $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->username,'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
                $this->page->profile();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class = "alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email/Password</div>');
                $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
                $this->page->login();

            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone please help me how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261007/not-giving-access-to-certain-method-in-controller-when-session-is-not-set-in-cod/31316000#31316000

Comment: you can use session concept. Please check the whether that session exist or not. Please check and confirm

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor to every applicable controller.
Let the constructor check if the user is logged in, possibly by checking if a particular session exists. If it doesn't redirect to the login page.

Something like below

```
   function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('userid')){
            redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this at the top of the page you don't want it accessed when not logged in (supposing you've already set session data)

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    redirect(base_url());
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before showing that page, you should check whether that session exist or not, like `if($this->session->userdata('username'))`. If exists, show that page, if not show any warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if ($this->session->userdata('login') == true) {
   redirect('controller');
}
```

Login Controller

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html','security'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function index()
    {

     if ($this->session->userdata('login') == true) {
        redirect('controller');
      }
        //get form input
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fail
            $this->load->view('content_login');
        }
        else
        {
            //check user credentials
            $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($username, $password);
            if(count($uresult)>0)
            {
                //set session
                $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->username,'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
                $this->page->profile();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class = "alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email/Password</div>');
                $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
                $this->page->login();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Couple things I noticed also in Codeigniter 3 + versions the first letter must only be upper case on FILENAME and Controller Class

Also you don't need to close the controllers and model with `?>` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

If for example you don't want the user to enter a function without login, you could check the session in the constructor of the class.

If it's only for a specific function, you could just also check the session in the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper file login_helper.php

```
function check_login( $session ) {
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $CI->load->helper('url');
     if(!$session->userdata('login')){
         redirect(base_url());
     }

}
```

Now use this helper function in controllers where login is mandatory

```
class page extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');    
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->status = $this->config->item('status'); 
    $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
}

function index() {
    $this->load->view('page_header');
    $this->load->view('content_front');
    $this->load->view('page_footer');
}


function login() {
    $this->load->view('page_header');
    $this->load->view('content_login');
    $this->load->view('page_footer');
}

function register() {

   $this->load->view('page_header');
   $this->load->view('content_register');
   $this->load->view('page_footer');

}  


function profile(){
    check_login();
    $this->load->view('page_header');
    $this->load->view('content_profile');
    $this->load->view('page_footer');

}

function success() {
    $this->load->view('page_header');
    $this->load->view('content_success');
    $this->load->view('page_footer');
}

function logout()
{
        //destroy session
    $data = array('login' => '', 'uname' => '', 'uid' => '');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect('page/index');
}


}
?>
```

Note: add login_helper in autoload.php in config folder.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('login','url','cookie');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<p class="alert alert-danger">Please login to view this page.</p>');
            redirect('login_c');
            exit;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.